# Is it possible to find the angular speed of a set of interconnected bars?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a hydraulic cylinder held to the ground which is connected to two arms $AB$ and $BC$. In the instant that $\alpha=\beta=60^{\circ}$
>   the cylinder transmits to $A$ a speed of
>   $v_{A}=1.2\sqrt{3}\,\frac{m}{s}$ (to the left). Find the angular speed
>   in $\frac{rad}{s}$ of the bars $BC$ and $AB$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]
The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&4.8\frac{rad}{s}\,\textrm{and}\,2.4\frac{rad}{s}\\
2.&2.4\frac{rad}{s}\,\textrm{and}\,4.8\frac{rad}{s}\\
3.&2.4\frac{rad}{s}\,\textrm{and}\,1.2\frac{rad}{s}\\
4.&3.6\frac{rad}{s}\,\textrm{and}\,1.8\frac{rad}{s}\\
5.&4.8\frac{rad}{s}\,\textrm{and}\,3.6\frac{rad}{s}\\
\end{array}$

I'm totally lost in this question. Can somebody instruct me exactly how am I supposed to find the angular speed?.

The only thing which I can barely remember is that the torque is related with the angular acceleration but I'm not sure if this will be applied here. Can an answer be **detailed the most as possible** so I can get the idea of what's going on here?.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $(i,j)$ a fixed orthonormal frame where $i$ is horizontal and $j$ vertical. You have following equations for the speeds of points $A, B, C$ using relative speed formula:

$$\begin{cases}
v_A &= -(1.2 \sqrt{3})i\\
v_B &= v_A + \dot{\alpha}AB(- (\sin \alpha) i + (\cos \alpha) j)\\
v_B &=  (\dot{\alpha}+\dot{\beta})BC(- \sin (\alpha+\beta) i + \cos (\alpha+\beta) j)
\end{cases}$$ as $v_C =0$.

Therefore
$$-(1.2 \sqrt{3})i+\dot{\alpha}AB(- (\sin \alpha) i + (\cos \alpha) j)-(\dot{\alpha}+\dot{\beta})BC(- \sin (\alpha+\beta) i + \cos (\alpha+\beta)=0$$

Based on that you get the two real equations (one for each coordinate):

$$\begin{cases}
1.2 \sqrt{3} + \dot{\alpha}AB\sin \alpha- (\dot{\alpha}+\dot{\beta})BC\sin (\alpha+\beta) &=0\\
\dot{\alpha}AB\cos \alpha - (\dot{\alpha}+\dot{\beta})BC\cos (\alpha+\beta) &=0
\end{cases}$$

From which you can get $\dot{\alpha}, \dot{\beta}$.